# How to make VSCode put C# attributes on the same line as the field/property?

Tags: styles, c#, visual-studio-code

Currently, when I write fields/properties with an attribute I write it like this...

```
[Serializable] public int ID { get; set }
```

Now, when I try to reformat the code in VSCode it moves them to the next line like this...

```
[Serializable]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

I would like to know if there's a way to disable this behavior.